# My test is returning this error: param is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

currently i am using this endpoint to create a new article

http://localhost:3000/api/v1/post/1/articles

in my test with rspec

i am doing this

```
RSpec.describe 'Api::V1::Articles', type: :request do
...
describe 'POST /create' do
      context "valid" do
        let!(:articles_params) { {
          name: "art", 
          post_id: @post.id
          } }
        it 'creates a new article' do
          expect { post :"/api/v1/posts/#{post.id}/articles" , params: articles_params }.to change(Article,:count).by(1)
        end
      end
    end
```

i am getting this error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: article
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because `:/api/v1/create` isn’t a valid symbol.

For request paths, you should provide them as strings instead, e.g.

```rb
expect { post "/api/v1/create", params: articles_params }
  .to change(Article, :count).by(1)
```

Comment: i have to send a param 1 in this case inside of the url api/v1/post/1/articles, this part post/1

Comment: @register You’d still send a string – remember that your request spec is sort of emulating a browser or an API client, which would send a string. So you could either hardcode a value, eg: `post '/api/v1/posts/1/articles'`, or you could use string interpolation, `post "/api/v1/posts/#{post.id}/articles"`.

Comment: there is not another way to do this "/api/v1/posts/#{post.id}/articles" ? improving more simple please